# shell script: time difference

Tags: bash, shell, time

This is my script to count the time difference between now and my date.
Is there any other way to do the same operation more efficiently?

```
#!/bin/bash

mydate=20141224 # yyyymmdd
mytime=00:00:00 #hh:mm:ss


current=$(date +%s)
target=$(date -d "$mydate $mytime" +%s)
diff=$((target-current))

day=$((diff / 86400))
left=$((diff - (day*86400)))

diff=$((left))

hour=$((diff / 3600))
left=$((diff - (hour * 3600)))

diff=$((left))

min=$((diff / 60))
left=$((diff -(min * 60)))

diff=$((left))

sec=$((diff))

echo $day"d" $hour"h" $min"min" $sec"sec"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. You seem to have forgotten to mention what's your problem. So, what's the question?

Comment: You could look at the modulo operator.